# Google secret manager is throwing "Invalid constructor input for AccessSecretVersionRequest" with python3.11 and secret-manager 2.16.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-3.11

## Below code snippet is throwing exception **Invalid constructor input for AccessSecretVersionRequest**

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager
from google.oauth2 import service_account

client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    name = client.secret_version_path(
        project=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
        secret=SECRET_NAME,
        secret_version=SECRET_VERSION
    )

    api_key = secretmanager_client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 7):

Google secret manager python SDK 2.16.0 expects first parameter should be request instead of name

```
def access_secret_version(self,
                          request: AccessSecretVersionRequest | dict | None = None,
                          *,
                          name: str | None = None,
                          retry: Retry | _MethodDefault | object = gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT,
                          timeout: float | object = gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT,
                          metadata: Sequence[tuple[str, str]] = ()) -> AccessSecretVersionResponse
```

Instead of directly passing the name in the function below

```
api_key = secretmanager_client.access_secret_version(name).payload.data.decode("utf-8")
```

use parameter_name=value like below

```
get_response_api_key = secretmanager_client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: wow, thanks for this snippet, I bumped into this today as well

Answer (score 0):

The you request the secret from google has changed as of version 2.0 of `google-cloud-secret-manager`. So you need to do it like this:

```
get_response_api_key = secretmanager_client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name}).payload.data.decode("utf-8")
```